# Neural network function approximation - line intersection

Tags: neural-networks

I have approximate my 2D function `f(x) = y` with a simple feed forward neural network. The result is quite OK. I am  able to compute derivatives at points from neural network.

However, is it possible to compute an intersection point of NN approximation function with a line, given by two points `[Ax, Ay]` and `[Bx, By]`?

Comment: Your question is not fully clear: You have a scalar 2D function? And a line segment given by two 3D points? (e.g. NN $z=f[x,y]$ and $A=[x_A,y_A,z_A]$?)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 I have edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a root-finding problem, assuming an intersection exists.

Your line *segment* is given by the set of points
\begin{align}y[t] &= y_A+(y_B-y_A)t \\
x[t] &= x_A+(x_B-x_A)t
\end{align}
for $t\in[0,1]$.

So for an intersection, you have
$$g[t] = y[t] -f\big[x[t]\big]=0$$

This can be solved for $t$ using any [root-finding method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm). For the 1D case, a derivative-free method would probably be fine (in Matlab I would use `fzero()`, corresponding to [Brent's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method)). As you can calculate the derivative, you could also use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), but to be [reliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Failure_of_the_method_to_converge_to_the_root) this will usually need to be combined with other methods, e.g. [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Bisection_method).

(Most reliable methods will require a starting interval $[t_\min,t_\max]$ containing a root, i.e. where $g[t_\min]\,g[t_\min]<0$, and they will maintain this condition as the algorithm proceeds.)